# Materialize CSS data-error Attribute

Tags: css, materialize

I was trying to style my form with Materialize CSS and there's something a little awkward with the `data-success` and `data-error` attributes: the words in the attribute appear to display in a vertical column, instead of displaying horizontally underneath the input field line. Here's a JS fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/8zgvyakn/1/. In a somewhat crowded form where such a lengthy error attribute may be necessary, the red text overlaps with other form fields. Is there any way around this, or is this a MaterializeCSS limitation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error text is an after of the label edit the width of the label to 100% and that should make the after 100% aswell.